# Skim values from middle layer in data structure

Tags: r, list, vector, apply

- I have a list where each item is a list referring to an excel workbook.
- Of those workbooks, each item is a list referring to the sheets within that workbook.
- Of the sheets, each item is a vector referring to the column names on that sheet.
- I am interested only in the name of the first column of each sheet in each vector

With these figures, I am creating a new structure to be slotted into a data frame

- Each row will still refer to a worksheet
- Each item within a point will be a vector of all of the first columns' names

It's a bit hard to paste sample data due to the nature of the data types to read so hopefully it is clear enough from my description.

As such, if `l1` represents the aforementioned list, then `l2` represents the following list:

`list(c((Worksheet1, Sheet1, A1), (Worksheet1, Sheet2, A1), (Worksheet1, Sheet3, A1)),
      c((Worksheet2, Sheet1, A1), (Worksheet2, Sheet2, A1), (Worksheet2, Sheet3, A1))`,

thus returning a list of vectors of top left cells

I can complete this using a concentric for loops, but I can't work out the wording to use the apply family here (or the map family for that matter). How do I trace along a list in such a way?

My best attempt using my knowledge (that doesn't just spit out an error) would be

`l2 <- lapply(l1, "[[", 1)`

however that returns the vector of all of the columns in the first sheet of each workbook, which isn't quite what I'm after.

dput EDIT:

```
structure(list(`Sheet 1` = structure(list(Sheet1 = c("Claim Status Report", 
"X__1", "Report A0817B"), Sheet2 = c("Standard Claims Lodgement-year Costs Breakdown Summary", 
"X__1", "X__2", "X__3", "X__4", "X__5", "X__6", "X__7", "X__8", 
"X__9", "X__10", "X__11", "X__12", "X__13", "X__14", "X__15", 
"X__16", "X__17", "X__18", "X__19"), Sheet3 = c("Standard Claims Lodgement-year Costs Breakdown by Claim", 
"X__1", "X__2", "X__3", "X__4", "X__5", "X__6", "X__7", "X__8", 
"X__9", "X__10", "X__11", "X__12", "X__13", "X__14", "X__15", 
"X__16", "X__17", "X__18", "X__19", "X__20", "X__21"), Sheet4 = "Claims with Statistical Case Estimate Variations over $1000", 
    Sheet5 = "Claims Received from  01/01/2018 to 31/01/2018", 
    Sheet6 = "Minor Claims received between 01/01/2018 and 31/01/2018", 
    Sheet7 = c("Medical Certificates Received between 01/01/2018 and 31/01/2018", 
    "X__1", "X__2", "X__3", "X__4", "X__5", "X__6", "X__7", "X__8", 
    "X__9", "X__10", "X__11"), Sheet8 = c("All (net) Payments entered between 01/01/2018 and 31/01/2018", 
    "X__1", "X__2", "X__3", "X__4", "X__5", "X__6", "X__7", "X__8", 
    "X__9", "X__10")), .Names = c("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", 
"Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "Sheet7", "Sheet8")), `Sheet 2` = structure(list(
    Sheet1 = c("Claim Status Report", "X__1", "Report A0817B"
    ), Sheet2 = c("Standard Claims Lodgement-year Costs Breakdown Summary", 
    "X__1", "X__2", "X__3", "X__4", "X__5", "X__6", "X__7", "X__8", 
    "X__9", "X__10", "X__11", "X__12", "X__13", "X__14", "X__15", 
    "X__16", "X__17", "X__18", "X__19"), Sheet3 = c("Standard Claims Lodgement-year Costs Breakdown by Claim", 
    "X__1", "X__2", "X__3", "X__4", "X__5", "X__6", "X__7", "X__8", 
    "X__9", "X__10", "X__11", "X__12", "X__13", "X__14", "X__15", 
    "X__16", "X__17", "X__18", "X__19", "X__20", "X__21"), Sheet4 = "Claims with Statistical Case Estimate Variations over $1000", 
    Sheet5 = c("Medical Certificates Received between 01/12/2017 and 31/12/2017", 
    "X__1", "X__2", "X__3", "X__4", "X__5", "X__6", "X__7", "X__8", 
    "X__9", "X__10", "X__11"), Sheet6 = c("All (net) Payments entered between 01/12/2017 and 31/12/2017", 
    "X__1", "X__2", "X__3", "X__4", "X__5", "X__6", "X__7", "X__8", 
    "X__9", "X__10")), .Names = c("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", 
"Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6"))), .Names = c("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2"
))
```

Comment: could you please share the list structure of the parent `list` using `dput(head(list))`? Even the `dput(list[[1]])` would be a great help.

Comment: I've added the first two items in the list.

Comment: Please check if my code produces the expected result or some modification is required.

Comment: Did it not work for you?

Comment: I have not had a chance to test it yet. Be patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
l2<-lapply(l1,function(x){tmp<-sapply(x,"[[",1,USE.NAMES = FALSE);mapply(c,names(tmp),tmp,SIMPLIFY = FALSE,USE.NAMES = FALSE)})
desired<-mapply(function(x,y){lapply(y,function(z){c(x,z)})},names(l2),l2,USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```